# make helm-list-elisp-packages use cache

Tags: helm

Every time I use the command `helm-list-elisp-packages` it downloads all the index files from melpa, gnu etc. Is there a way to make it rely on the previous cache of the index files ?

I know there is `package-list-packages-no-fetch` which does what I want but it doesn't have the nice helm interface.

Comment: You should open an issue on Helm repo to requeste this feature..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `helm-list-elisp-package` already does what you want: it only downloads descriptions of all configured ELPA packages for the first time.

Even without downloading, It may still looks slow because of a great number of packages. In this case, you can use `helm-resume` to resurrect previously invoked `helm-list-elisp-package`, it is much faster.

Please also see the implementation of `helm-list-elisp-package` and the docstring of `helm-resume`.

**Update**

Don't fetch the updated list of packages:

```
(defun helm-list-elisp-packages-no-fetch ()
  (interactive)
  (setq helm-el-package--initialized-p t)
  (helm-list-elisp-packages nil))
```

Do fetch the updated list of packages:

```
C-u M-x helm-list-elisp-packages
```

Only fetch for the first time during one Emacs session and don't refetch for the rest time:

```
M-x helm-list-elisp-packages
```

Comment: The problem is If I quit emacs and re-open it again, it downloads the index file again from the remote repositories.

Comment: Thanks, in the latest version of `helm`, this command has been added. Related issue: https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/971